# dynamodb access pattern for timeseries data

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

In AWS documentation for dynamodb they describe the best practices for storing timeseries data in dynamodb (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-time-series.html).

What is the best practice for accessing this data when you want following access pattern:

- Get rows between two data ranges that are not a hole unit like an hour or a week. Eg. from 2019-11-03 22:01:50 to 2019-11-04 04:10:35. As you can not query hashkey, and inserting a dummy hashkey sounds like a bad idea. If i use 2019-11-03 as primary key then i have to query first 2019-11-03 and then 2019-11-04 which also sounds like a bad solution.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call multiple queries a "bad" solution...

In fact, since you should be able to do them in parallel, overall response time might be less than if you could do then with a single query.

You don't provide any estimate of the number of writes/reads per second, nor if you have other access requirements; so it's hard to say what would work best.

I will point out that AWS time series example supports very high volume of data flowing into the table.

If your volume isn't that high, you might be able to have a hash key of `YYYY-MM` instead of `YYYY-MM-DD`.  Sort key would then be `DD HH:MM:SS.xxxxxx`

Still would need multiple queries if you query across months...

Comment: I'm expecting less than 1000 write of new data per day and read in the order of 100 querys per day. You could argue that in this data size it could be a viable option to use a dummy hashkey like '#' for all rows and then the timestamp as sortkey. This will give the desired result. But I do not think that will scale well. Because all data will be put on one partition.